# Autowiring with quartz throws nullpointerexception

Tags: spring, quartz

I'm using spring 4.1.2 with quartz 2.2.3 and the business in the code below throws nullpointerexception. interfacePedidoBusiness is always coming null. Although sounds to have many solutions, neither of them was useful for me. Could you please give me some suggestion?

```
public class PedidoPagoJob implements Job
{
@Autowired
private InterfacePedidoBusiness interfacePedidoBusiness;

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
{
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

    try 
    {
        List<Pedido> pedidos = interfacePedidoBusiness.buscarPedidoPorStatus(Short.parseShort("3"));
```

Comment: Can you add your definition of autowired bean?

Comment: That definition with @Autowired in the code a nove.

Comment: I meant code above.